# How to wrap cylindrical object around 2 posts

Tags: modeling

Currently working on a chair and can't get the back rest right. It's essentially a cloth draped around the wood legs that extend all the way up into posts. Anyway, I tried taking a cylinder, extruding half of it over to the other post but can't seem to get the trajectory and rotation right. Any ideas for how I can accomplish this in a more accurate way? Would love for it to look more realistic so any tips and critiques would be appreciated.

[image]

Here are my reference images

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see a reason to model it with cylinders. Duplicate border edges of that place from the chair legs, separate them into new object and create faces between them.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you’re pretty close. I probably would have started with a cube. Because it’s usually better to start with less detail rather than more. And from the photo, it looks like the ends of the backrest are a bit flat rather than completely rounded over like starting with a cylinder gives you.

Start with a cube and get the top left corner from n the correct place at the end of one vertical post. I edit mode grab the bottom face and pull it down and slightly forward so you have a skewed rectangle matching the slope of the back.

Now grab the side face and move it over to the other post. Now you only have 4 vertices on each end of the backrest to adjust to get the alignment right.

Now that the basic form is there start edging details: vertical edge loops to add the contour between posts, bevel the edges with only one or two subdivisions to make them more rounded and soft looking. Once this level of detail is done, subdivide and/or sculpt it to add the asymmetrical details of a soft cushion.

Answer (score 0):

Try the *ShrinkWarp* modifier (add more geometry), or try making a simulation.

Try going into wireframe and by pressing the view keys (<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>7</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd>) getting your vertices right.